# Android : Service/Activity should start after some time, while the screen is off or user is not using his phone till 5 minutes

Tags: android, service

I'm having the problem that I want to have a service/activity running after some time, after I turned off the screen and put the phone into my pocket or user not using his phone til 5 minutes.

Is there somewhere a system timer, which can call my app to wake up and accquire the wakelock then. (screen is off all time and in my pocket)

Comment: use Alarm Service  for this task and asign time when time is come tha activity and service come

Comment: Create Receiver for Screen Off event : Create new Service use Timer Class for setting time delay : invoke your Activity or Service

Comment: we have used in this the Dream Service Because this is like daydream And we want to display video as a screen saver when user is not touching his phone till 5 minutes

Comment: one crazy idea is to use the push notification !!! Let your app send info to server when the client close it, and then after 5 minutes send a push notification to the application !!!

Comment: @BinaryMan we dont have send the notification.

Comment: @BinaryMan we want to start the dream service when my phone is on idle state or user is not touch his phone till 5 minute. This is like screen saver App